# Sorting a d.frame by a column of another d.frame R

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I'm aware this question was made before, but my problem is a little bit different from what I have seen. And I can't solve it with previous questions and answers.

I want to sort a data frame using the column of another data frame. But with a peculiarity. The First data frame has several rows for each IID. Here is an example of the data structure and problem:

```
x<-c(rep("sc256",times=5),rep("sc784",times=5),rep("sc326",times=5),rep("sc120",times=5))
x2<-c("sc256","sc784","sc326","sc120")
y<-round(runif(20,1,10),digits=3)
y2<-round(runif(20,10,20),digits=3)
y3<-c(2,1,2,1)

M1<-data.frame(x,y,y2)
M2<-data.frame(x2,y3)
M2$y3<-as.factor(M2$y3)

M2.s<-M2[order(M2$y3),]
M1.s<-M1[order(M2.s$x),]
```

This script produces a data frame M1.s like the following:

```
      x     y     y2
2 sc256 6.585 17.115
3 sc256 7.794 14.855
4 sc256 5.038 15.650
1 sc256 7.451 16.205
```

Which is not what I'm looking for. What I'm looking for is a M1 data base arranged by the M2 first column something like this:

```
    x     y     y2
6  sc784 2.828 13.974
7  sc784 3.966 17.332
8  sc784 4.733 12.948
9  sc784 6.933 12.088
10 sc784 3.182 14.913
11 sc326 5.189 11.808
12 sc326 5.660 19.475
13 sc326 2.403 14.719
14 sc326 4.881 13.884
15 sc326 3.913 10.947
16 sc120 9.122 17.839
17 sc120 4.676 10.343
18 sc120 9.184 18.367
19 sc120 7.671 18.212
20 sc120 5.302 11.500
1  sc256 7.451 16.205
2  sc256 6.585 17.115
3  sc256 7.794 14.855
4  sc256 5.038 15.650
5  sc256 1.684 14.698
```

This is indeed a small sample of my problem, since in my real data I have several thousand rows. When I'm trying to apply this script to my real data I got this error:

```
Error in Fula[order(Fula.s$levels.dat.IID.), ] : subscript out of bounds
```

Which I don't know what means!

Comment: Hi, if any answer solves your problem can you click on "accept it" so that other people can see it? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a possibility:

```
> M1.s<-M1[order(M2$y3[match(M1$x,M2$x)]),]
> M1.s
       x     y     y2
6  sc784 5.193 19.458
7  sc784 6.307 14.398
8  sc784 1.042 11.436
9  sc784 5.392 15.096
10 sc784 9.124 13.521
16 sc120 6.496 19.087
17 sc120 3.128 12.793
18 sc120 8.870 10.844
19 sc120 1.245 18.832
20 sc120 3.448 11.475
1  sc256 2.426 13.556
2  sc256 4.208 11.488
3  sc256 6.842 12.782
4  sc256 9.088 13.648
5  sc256 5.746 11.052
11 sc326 6.421 17.500
12 sc326 6.938 16.412
13 sc326 8.216 14.833
14 sc326 6.500 10.606
15 sc326 3.897 10.517
```

Answer (score 1):

In your question both the M1 and M2 data.frame have the same order of the first columns (Or I'm missing something in your question). I am assuming you have one data.frame which is large that you want to sort by the order the first column of a shorter dataframe. Since these columns are factors we can do this by releveling the larger dataframe to the order of the short one:

```
x<-c(rep("sc256",times=5),rep("sc784",times=5),rep("sc326",times=5),rep("sc120",times=5))
# Change the order of second data.frame because otherwise nothing needs to be ordered
x2<-c("sc784","sc326","sc256", "sc120")
y<-round(runif(20,1,10),digits=3)
y2<-round(runif(20,10,20),digits=3)
y3<-c(2,1,2,1)

M1<-data.frame(x,y,y2)
M2<-data.frame(x2,y3)
M2$y3<-as.factor(M2$y3)

new.order <- M2$x2
M1.s <- M1
M1.s$x <- ordered(M1.s$x, new.order)
M1.s <- M1.s[order(M1.s$x),]
M1.s

       x     y     y2
6  sc784 5.555 13.150
7  sc784 8.647 12.967
8  sc784 7.338 11.909
9  sc784 1.272 15.863
10 sc784 6.477 17.091
11 sc326 5.240 15.350
12 sc326 7.923 18.450
13 sc326 7.258 13.867
14 sc326 3.132 19.233
15 sc326 4.373 15.142
1  sc256 8.160 17.038
2  sc256 1.775 15.460
3  sc256 9.310 19.261
4  sc256 8.354 14.930
5  sc256 1.724 19.410
16 sc120 8.284 12.614
17 sc120 1.479 17.149
18 sc120 8.164 14.561
19 sc120 3.469 16.971
20 sc120 4.083 10.136
```

If you want to order by some other column like `M2$y3` just order M2 first and then repeat:

```
M2 <- M2[order(M2$y3),]
sorted.by.y3 <- M2$x2
M1.s$x <- ordered(M1.s$x, sorted.by.y3)
M1.s[order(M1.s$x),]
M1.s

       x     y     y2
1  sc256 8.160 17.038
2  sc256 1.775 15.460
3  sc256 9.310 19.261
4  sc256 8.354 14.930
5  sc256 1.724 19.410
6  sc784 5.555 13.150
7  sc784 8.647 12.967
8  sc784 7.338 11.909
9  sc784 1.272 15.863
10 sc784 6.477 17.091
11 sc326 5.240 15.350
12 sc326 7.923 18.450
13 sc326 7.258 13.867
14 sc326 3.132 19.233
15 sc326 4.373 15.142
16 sc120 8.284 12.614
17 sc120 1.479 17.149
18 sc120 8.164 14.561
19 sc120 3.469 16.971
20 sc120 4.083 10.136
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr` library:

```
library(dplyr)
M2 %>% arrange(y3) %>% select(x2) %>%  left_join(M1, by=c("x2"="x"))
####    x2     y     y2
#### 1  sc784 4.891 12.442
#### 2  sc784 3.850 19.154
#### 3  sc784 5.181 14.104
#### 4  sc784 1.359 11.206
#### 5  sc784 7.922 10.257
#### 6  sc120 8.402 10.958
#### 7  sc120 6.724 17.047
#### 8  sc120 5.451 18.919
#### 9  sc120 2.160 13.177
#### 10 sc120 9.573 10.977
#### 11 sc256 7.034 15.335
#### 12 sc256 7.758 19.715
#### 13 sc256 3.199 19.395
#### 14 sc256 7.698 10.704
#### 15 sc256 7.164 12.088
#### 16 sc326 8.525 17.018
#### 17 sc326 7.844 15.564
#### 18 sc326 7.008 16.835
#### 19 sc326 4.272 10.176
#### 20 sc326 5.889 17.272
```

Note: you should define a `set.seed` so that it's reproducible...

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I'm having a problem when I use the script with my real data: I get this error: 
     Fula.sor<-Fula.s %>% arrange (fr2) %>% select(levels.dat.IID.) %>% left_join(Fula,by=c("IID"="levels.dat.IID."))

Comment: @Cebs ok, seems that the youdid'nt paste the full error text...?